# It's possible to create one-shoot app with Actions on Google?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am completely new to the "Actions on Google" world, but following some tutorials (like [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/index.html#0)) i have already achieved good results.

## My test

With Google Assistant and/or Google Home mini send my commands to a personal nodejs online server.

To do this:

- i have created a new project on https://console.actions.google.com/
- selected **conversational** option

[image: conversational option]

- selected **create action** / **custom intent** option

[image: custom intent]

- from **Dialogflow** i have personalized the **Default Welcome Intent** and created a new **Intent** with the **Fulfillment** option set to Enable **webhook call for this intent**

[image]

- And obviously, from **Dialogflow** > **Fulfillment**, i have enabled the **Webhook** option (with the url of my nodejs app), and not the **Inline editor**.

This procedure works, when my app recognizes my custom **intent**, the answer is sent to my nodejs app online.

## My problem

The procedure works, but i always have to do 2 steps before i can perform my action:

1) Hey Google, talk with "nameofmyapp"

2) Say the command

## My goal

Execute my command directly without always having to do this 2 steps.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! Google calls this "[deep linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/define-actions#define_additional_actions)". With this, you'll be able to do something like

> Hey Google, ask nameof myapp to command

See the documentation for details, but in short you'll

1. Make sure you have an Intent for the command in Dialogflow, with several possible phrases that can be used to trigger it.

   - These phrases should be what you'd say under "command" in the example above - you'd omit the "to" part.
2. Go to the *Integrations* section in Dialogflow, under the *Google Assistant* integration.
3. In the *Implicit invocation* section, select the Intent that you'd like to allow as a deep-linked Intent.

If the command takes action and then should quit, make sure either you have set this in Dialogflow or your fulfillment calls `app.close();`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After writing the question on SO i found this docs : https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/implicit , which is what you showed. But being my commands, home automation commands, I think they conflict with Google's smart home logic.

Comment: For example i have "Turn on room lights", but Google Assistant replies by saying that lights are not configured

Comment: Implicit discovery is slightly different - that is Google picking what a user has said and matching it to your Action. What I outline was an explicit invocation with a deep linking command.

Comment: If you're looking to do a Smart Home action - that is a different creature altogether. See https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/ for details.